# GIT fecth and rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-fetch

I am new to GIT and not able to understand how the second rebase command resulted in merge issue:

```
$ git rebase origin/develop
Current branch feature/featurename is up to date.

$ git fetch
remote: Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Services
remote: We noticed you're using an older version of Git. For the best experience, upgrade to a newer version.
remote: Found 50 objects to send. (31 ms)
Unpacking objects: 100% (50/50), done.
From https://.....
   df825005..000000cf  develop          -> origin/develop

$ git rebase origin/develop
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: .....
C:/work/.../rebase-apply/patch:61: trailing whitespace
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       br/br
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging case/TTest.cpp
 CONFLICT (submodule): Merge conflict in br/br
```

I understand that both rebase and fetch will refer to origin/develop however I do have a 'set-upstream' branch in our VSTS (build system) - so did the fetch fetched from my feature branch in VSTS?

Answer (score 2):

Git just told you in its output what happened:

```
Current branch feature/featurename is up to date.
```

This means that, at the moment, before fetch, your branch indeed is based on origin/development. So your history looks something like this:

```
  feature/featurename
      /
-o---o
  \
  origin/development
```

Now you called the `git fetch` command which checks if there were new commits pushed to the remote repository. Turns out, there were, and `git` informs you what was changed with the message:

```
From https://.....
   df825005..000000cf  develop          -> origin/develop
```

This means that branch `develop` on the remote repository `https://.....` moved from `df825005` to `000000cf` (nice hash, btw), so your remote branch `origin/develop` was updated accordingly. Now your history looks like this:

```
  feature/featurename
      /
-o---o
  \
    --o <- origin/development
```

The branch `feature/featurename` is no longer based on top of `origin/development`, so when you run rebase you have to go through the whole process (branch no longer up to date and no fast-forward possible)

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
```

This is a preparation step for doing a rebase - `HEAD` is put at the top of the `origin/develop` branch as it will now try to put your commits there.

```
Applying: .....
```

Here was the name of the commit git is now applying where `HEAD` is. Right now its the top of the `origin/develop` but if you had more commits to be rebased it would move forward, obviously.

```
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
```

Git failed to automatically apply your commit, as there were files modified both in your commit and in the `origin/develop` branch. So now git will have to do...

```
Auto-merging case/TTest.cpp
```

The clever git alghoritms might avoid conflicts in this file so it will try to automerge it

```
CONFLICT (submodule): Merge conflict in br/br
```

No luck! Unfortunately, git wasn't able to automerge the file and has left you with this responsibility. You either have some exotic version of git, or you've trimmed the output, but git will usually include one more very helpful line:

```
When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
```

So now all you have to do is resolve the conflict in the usual way, and once you're done, do `git rebase --continue`. Now git will try to apply the next commit, if there are any left.

I strongly recommend reading a tutorial of your choice about git - it seems like you are highly confused about the very fundamental concepts of git, which are very different from version control systems like svn

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - but my question was why the first rebase stated that Current branch feature/featurename is up to date. What did fetch do and from where it pulled changes such that next rebase found work to do?

Comment: @Prakash oh sorry, totally misunderstood your question. I added the explanation of fetch at the beginning of my answer

Comment: Thanks once again-but the time difference in between the first rebase and fetch cmd was almost some seconds diff-please confirm if you are stating that within those seconds some new commits got added to origin/development branch-I am assuming that since local branch 'set-upstream' is set to my VSTS (Visual Studio Team Service) feature branch fetch cmd pulled remote commits into local repo and hence the next rebase cmd resulted into merge issue -  so is it that when 'set-upstream' is set we should not do fetch cause it is a copy of local branch that we have pushed in remote? This is my guess

Comment: @Prakash `git fetch` when run without arguments fetches from all remotes, all branches. In this case it was the `origin/develop` branch that was changed since your last fetch. Nothing changed on your feature branch.

Comment: Thanks once again then why did rebase (first command) initially stated that my branch is up to date? So is it not that git fetch got details from my remote feature branch also? Rebase command should have brought every thing from origin/development branch

Comment: oh I think I see where your confusion comes from. Have you worked previously with centralised vcs like svn? Git is different in the sense that it doesn't require constant connection to the main repository - when you run rebase, commit, stash etc, git doesn't download/upload anything. The only commands that do communicate with the server are fetch, pull and push. Until you run either of these, git doesn't update your local copy! This is why at the moment of running `git rebase` your branch was up to date, and only after `git fetch` became out of date.

Comment: Well I do not believe so - then the second rebase should not have stated so

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that both rebase and fetch will refer to `origin/develop` ...

This isn't quite right.

What `git fetch` does is connect *your* Git (which has an independent copy of all of its commits—your own commits and everyone else's commits as of the last time you connected your Git to all the other Gits you connect-to)—to some other Git.

The other Git may have commits that you don't.  If so, your Git asks their Git for the commits that they have, that you don't.  They hand over their commits-that-they-have-that-you-don't; your Git stores those commits permanently, in your repository, under their hash IDs; and then your Git records, for your usage, which commits are their *tip* commits.  That is, they have a branch named `develop`.  You just got a listing, from them, of what commit hash their `develop` names.  But you may well have *your own branch* named `develop`, so your Git does not touch *your* `develop` at all.  Instead, it just updates your memory of *their* `develop`, which your Git calls `origin/develop`.

When you run `git rebase origin/develop`, your Git *does not call up another Git*, it just looks at your saved memory in your own `origin/develop`.  So your first `git rebase` did nothing as the memory you had of their `develop`, stored in your `origin/develop`, did not require doing anything.  Then you ran `git fetch`, which obtained new commits from their Git and updated your memory of their `develop` by updating your `origin/develop`.  Then your second `git rebase` looked at your updated memory, found that there was something to do, did it, and that process resulted in the merge conflict you saw.

Comment: Thanks for the information - "...their Git and updated your memory of their develop by updating your origin/develop.." - would git submodule update --remote before first rebase command would do the same (git fetch followed by git rebase)? Isn't it that origin/develop is only one (single) and all code push from other GIT updates origin/develop?

Comment: `git submodule update` will sometimes run `git fetch`, and sometimes won't; see the `git submodule` documentation for all the details. Your own `origin/develop` identifies one commit; it's updated only in a few cases, including a full `git fetch` from that remote, and a successful `git push` that updates that remote's `develop` name. A `git push` won't update unrelated remote-tracking names, and you can restrict `git fetch` to updating only one or a few specific remote-tracking names; but an unrestricted `git fetch` will generally update all remote-tracking names.